# How do I stop one of the countup timers (say countup2) once the project is complete and display the elapsed time till completion?

Tags: javascript, countdown

I am running several timers on one page.  I am uncertain as to how to stop an individual timer when that particular project is complete and still display the timer showing the total time it took to complete.

For instance, if countup2 is completed on January 5, 2019 what/where would be the proper syntax?

```
HTML

<div class="countup" id="countup1">
  <p class="days">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefDays">Days</p>
  <p class="hours">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefHours">hrs</p>
  <p class="minutes">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefMinutes">min</p>
  <p class="seconds">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefSeconds">sec</p>
</div>
<div class="countup" id="countup2">
  <p class="days">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefDays">Days</p>
  <p class="hours">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefHours">hrs</p>
  <p class="minutes">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefMinutes">min</p>
  <p class="seconds">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefSeconds">sec</p>
</div>
<div class="countup" id="countup3">
  <p class="days">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefDays">Days</p>
  <p class="hours">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefHours">hrs</p>
  <p class="minutes">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefMinutes">min</p>
  <p class="seconds">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefSeconds">sec</p>
</div>


<script>

/*
 * Basic Count Up from Date and Time
 */
window.onload = function() {
  // Month,Day,Year,Hour,Minute,Second
  upTime('jan,01,2018,00:00:00', 'countup1'); // ****** Change this line!
  upTime('dec,01,2018,10:10:10', 'countup2'); // ****** Change this line!
  upTime('dec,01,2018,10:10:10', 'countup3'); // ****** Change this line!

}

function upTime(countTo, id) {
  now = new Date();
  countTo = new Date(countTo);
  difference = (now - countTo);

  days = Math.floor(difference / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24) * 1);
  hours = Math.floor((difference % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) / (60 * 60 * 
1000) * 1);
  mins = Math.floor(((difference % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 
1000)) / (60 * 1000) * 1);
  secs = Math.floor((((difference % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) % (60 * 60 * 
1000)) % (60 * 1000)) / 1000 * 1);

  idEl = document.getElementById(id);
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('days')[0].innerHTML = days;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('hours')[0].innerHTML = hours;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('minutes')[0].innerHTML = mins;
  idEl.getElementsByClassName('seconds')[0].innerHTML = secs;


  setInterval(function() {
    upTime(countTo, id);
  }, 1000);
}

</script>


<style>

.countup {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;

}

.countup p {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #F94EEE;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  min-width: 2.6rem;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) API for some examples on setting up timers.